# Is employer responsible to disclose workplace before hiring?

Tags: united-states, employment

I was originally hired to do some in office computer work. During my interviews, I was on the premises 3 times.  Employer showed me this “workplace”, my desk, etc. I worked there for about a month, and then out of the blue the employer told me I need to do work in the underground lab. Due to my health condition I’m unable to be exposed to that environment.  If I knew I would need to work there, I would NEVER accept the job. Is the employer responsible in any way to show the actual physical work place BEFORE hiring? Now they are saying “we told you”, but I don’t really remember them telling me. Also the job description doesn’t have any of it. I thought employer should show the actual working place , especially if it is not an ordinary one.  **Is there any law in the U.S. requiring the employer to disclose and **show** the actual physical work place?**

Answer (score 4):

In the US, persons with a disability are entitled to a reasonable accommodation for their disability. There is no requirement to tell an employee everything about their working conditions before a hire, in fact it would be illegal for the employer to ask "Do you have a disability that would prevent you from working underground?". Once hired, you can request an accommodation for your disability.

Comment: When i inhale the fumes from the lab (with or without a mask), i collapse with an asthma attack. They are firing me for this now. Is asthma considered a disability?

Comment: Nothing is a disability per se, but given your description, it fits the definition: see https://www.dol.gov/agencies/odep/publications/faqs/general

Comment: Is there any law (section title number or something ...) I can point my employer to. Maybe they read that law and reconsider firing>

Comment: @user37512 only a *reasonable* one. Moving the lab or not working in the lab, if that is what the job includes, is not reasonable

Comment: It's unlikely that they do not know of this law, but the Dept. of Labor FAQ on disabilities is enough. This is where you probably have to lawyer up.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any law in the U.S. requiring the employer to disclose and
> show the actual physical work place?

No. There is not. Your remedy is to either request an ADA accommodation, if that is viable, or to quit. If you can show that your decision to quit was a "constructive discharge" because you couldn't work in the conditions provided, you could still be eligible for unemployment benefits, even though normally, they are not available to someone who voluntarily quits a job.